# No module named tensorflow.contrib.learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have tried installing tenserflow in my ubuntu os but i get error as no module what may be the problem !!

My code :

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as learn
from sklearn import datasets, metrics

iris = datasets.load_iris()
feature_columns = learn.infer_real_valued_columns_from_input(iris.data)
classifier = learn.LinearClassifier(n_classes=3, feature_columns=feature_columns)
classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target, steps=200, batch_size=32)
iris_predictions = list(classifier.predict(iris.data, as_iterable=True))
score = metrics.accuracy_score(iris.target, iris_predictions)
print("Accuracy: %f" % score)
```

Comment: include the full error traceback.

Comment: which tensorflow version you are using? you should consider upgrading your tensorflow installation.

Comment: Have no idea !! Is there a way to update tenserflow !!!

Comment: But i tink i have updated tenserflow !! my pip verison is not new !!

Comment: if i update pip to newer version it say "You need any one requirement to update pip "!!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Flower_detection.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow.contrib.learn as learn
ImportError: No module named tensorflow.contrib.learn

Comment: FLower_detection is my python file with that code !!

Comment: Could you print `import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)`

Comment: How can I check whether I have installed tensorflow ?

Comment: you can type in your terminal `locate tensorflow`, or `whereis tensorflow`

Comment: You can also try to simply `import tensorflow`, to discard that the problem is that you have an older version, without the _tensorflow.contrib.learn_ module

Comment: This is the result for "whereis tensorflow"
"tensorflow:"    in terminal

Comment: "no module as tensorflow " this is result when i run "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/    ............ If i locate it shows me many files , and this shows i have tenserflow installed but its not working if i run it even as "import tensorflow"

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `import tensorflow.contrib.learn as learn` this library use Tensorflow 1.15 version.
install Tensorflow 1.15 using

```
pip install tensorflow==1.15
```